# Определить наличие проигрываемого звука Windows на Python

Tags: python, аудио

Пишу программу для анализа работы удаленных ПК. Необходимо определить проигрывается ли звук на удаленном ПК при подключении к нему. При подключении звук идет в мои динамики, поэтому просто скрипт определение наличия звука на ПК в Python. Может есть у кого что то готовое? или вырезка из кода?

Comment: В заголовке вроде добавил Windows

Comment: Не заметил `:)`